# HList traversal and mapping for Generic Case class

Tags: scala, apache-spark, shapeless

I am trying to traverse over an HList of custom case class RichColumnT to add columns to a spark Dataframe - Spark Dataframe/Dataset API provides df.withColumn(columnName, col("")) -> I have built the API using implicits to be able to do something like this - `df.addColumn[String]`

and the library would do 
`df.withColumn("someColumn", lit(""))`

for example where lit("") is default for a String column data type. Now I wanna be able to do this sort of thing with HList of RichColumns where T type parameter is different.

for eg. somehow `richColumnsHlist.map(PolyFunctionThatLooksLikeBelowButOnDifferentTType)`

Any suggestions? here is my code thus far -

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
  case class RichColumn[T](name: String)

  implicit class DataFrameImplicits(dataFrame: DataFrame) {

    def addColumn[T: TypeTag](name: String): DataFrame = {
      val t = typeOf[T]
      val df: DataFrame =  t match {
        case x if typeOf[T] <:< typeOf[String] ⇒ dataFrame.withColumn(name, lit(""))
        case x if typeOf[T] <:< typeOf[Int] ⇒ dataFrame.withColumn(name, lit(0))
        case x if typeOf[T] <:< typeOf[Double] ⇒ dataFrame.withColumn(name, lit(0d))
        case x if typeOf[T] <:< typeOf[Float] ⇒ dataFrame.withColumn(name, lit(0f))
      }
      df
    }
  }
}
object DataFrameAddColumnTest extends App {
  import Functions._
  import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local").getOrCreate()
  import spark.implicits._
  val df = Seq(1,2,3).toDF
  df.addColumn[Int]("addedColumn").columns.foreach(println)
}
```

and this is my

```
case class RichColumn[T](name: String)
```

Comment: Have you seen frameless? https://github.com/typelevel/frameless